# Printing Sysout logs from a jar file

Tags: java, coldfusion, cxf

1. I have a Web service client jar.
2. `clint.class` has a few messages logged to the Standard output (sysout).
3. I am trying to invoke the class methods using Cold Fusion script.

Questions:

1. How to print sysout of the client.java or client.class.
2. Client is invoking a Web Service. Should the Client class contain main method or is it not required?

Comment: 2) Every jar needs to have a main method. 1) Is the problem that you can't read the output of a jar file? To see System.out output from a jar, you need to open the jar from the console. Use command `java -jar MyJarFile.jar`

Comment: RE #1. When you say "print", do you mean for debugging purposes (only)? RE: #2 - It sounds like you are converting an example designed for java. CF does some things a bit differently. So it does not always make sense to handle things the same way. Are you sure you need to use this "client" class? Have you tried invoking the web service directly from CF, using either createObject or cfhttp?

Comment: #1 Thank you for your help. Yes it is for only debugging purpose and i want to verify sysout log messages from client class.                                   #2. Client is normal class and i am able to invoke web service .

Comment: RE #2 - What I meant is, are you able to invoke the web service directly in CF (without the client)? RE #1 0 What version of CF? CF9 and earlier send `System.out` to the standard log directory `{cf_root}\logs\coldfusion-out.log`. Not sure about CF10+. Check the logs directory.

Comment: I am able to invoke web service with client. I am able to invoke the webservice using soapUI.  Client application is following few security standards. I am new to coldfusion9 and can you please suggest how to invoke webservice using coldfusion9.

Comment: @user2707491 - Either [invoke it via `cfhttp`](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1809-making-soap-web-service-requests-with-coldfusion-and-cfhttp.htm) using the data structure from SoapUI. You could also try `createObject("webservice")`.  Pass in the WSDL and create an instance. Then invoke the appropriate method.  Give that a try. If you run into problems, open a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. By default, messages printed to [System.out](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) are appended to the `{cf_root}\runtime\logs\coldfusion-out.log` file. Side note, if you are running ColdFusion Express, the output is piped to the console window instead.
2. Regarding the `main` method, it is only required for running stand-alone applications in java. It is *not* required when invoking a class from ColdFusion.

As an aside, the `System.out` is probably for demo purposes only. It is discouraged in real applications. The general recommendation is to use a logging library instead, which offers much greater control and flexibility than basic print statements. One example is [Log4J](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/), which happens to be what ColdFusion uses internally.

Also, it sounds like you are converting an example designed for java. Given that CF has slightly different capabilities, so you may not even need to use the "client" class. Try invoking the web service directly from CF using either `createObject("webservice")` or `cfhttp`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. <code><html>
<body>
<cfscript>
 try {
  Webservice_client_Obj = CreateObject('java', 'com.tfp.ipr.soap.IBANServiceClient'); /* create an object connect to a Jar or Class file */
  Webservice_client_response = Webservice_Obj.validate('987654'); /* Passing value into a method */
 
 }
 catch (any e) {
  WriteOutput("Exception:  #e#");
 } 
</cfscript>
<cfoutput>
#Webservice_client_response#
</cfoutput>
</body>
</html> </code>  while running this, i am getting error as WEBSERVICE_CLIENT_RESPONSE is undefined. The specific sequence of files included.

Comment: (Edit) Did you mean to write `Webservice_Obj.validate()` instead of `Webservice_client_Obj.validate()`? Aside from that difference, hard to say what is wrong without seeing the API. Sounds like `validate()` is not actually returning anything. Is it supposed to return something or just `void`?  BTW, S.O. works a little differently than a forum: one question per thread. Since the syntax issue is a different topic, you should open a new thread. Be sure to include a public link to the API (if possible).